# R: Loop over a data.frame and create output table

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, geospatial, fips

Following script helps to query Census Bureau information with regard to places and their regional areas. It makes use of the [acs package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/acs.pdf). Problem: I would like to know how the following script can be adjusted so that it applies the `output` to all input cities.

#### Script

```
dput(data)

dat <- c("Albuquerque, NM", "Alpine, UT", "Anacortes, WA", "Anchorage, AK", "Ann Arbor, MI", "Arlington, MA", "Arlington, VA", "Artesia, CA", "Asheville, NC", "Astoria, NY", "Athens, GA", "Atlanta, GA", "Austin, TX", "Baltimore, MD", "Bellevue, WA", "Sunnyvale, CA")


# Load packages
library(tigris)   # County information
data(fips_codes)
library(acs)      # Census query

# Separate place and state names (needed for queries below)
dat <- data.frame(dat)
dat <- dat %>% separate(dat, c("place", "state_name"), ",")

# Get state names and abbreviations
states <- cbind(state.name, state.abb) %>% tbl_df()

# Script for a single query:

fips_codes <-fips_codes[c("state","state_code","county_code","county")]
colnames(fips_codes) = c("state.abb", "statefp", "countyfp", "county.name")
# Query county FIPS codes, join tables
output <- geo.lookup(state = "GA", place = "Athens")[2,] %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  left_join(states, by = "state.name") %>%
  left_join(fips_codes, by = c("county.name", "state.abb"))

output

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  state state.name   county.name place                                        place.name state.abb statefp countyfp
  <chr>      <chr>         <chr> <int>                                             <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <chr>
1    13    Georgia Clarke County  3440 Athens-Clarke County unified government (balance)        GA      13      059
```

As you can see, the script gives an output for a *single entry*, i.e. `geo.lookup(state = "GA", place = "Athens")`.

Now, how can I change the script so that it loops over all `dat` items and creates a data frame containing all the place, state.abbrev, state, county, countyfp etc. in a row? `dat` is already separated into place and state abbreviation.

**Bonus:** It would be great to see whether the [acs package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/acs.pdf) can also help to get the place/county related msa information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the `geo.lookup()` request in an `apply()` function as follows:

```
dat <- strsplit(c("Athens, GA", "Albuquerque, NM", "Alpine, UT", "Anacortes, WA"),",")

# Load packages
library(tigris)   # County information
data(fips_codes)
data(fips.state)
library(acs)  

theGeoLookups <- lapply(dat,function(x) {
    geo.lookup(state = trimws(x[2]), place = trimws(x[1]))[2,]
    # only return if we receive valid place data from geo.lookup()
    if("place.name" %in% colnames(aLookup)) return(aLookup)
    else return(NULL) 

})
aResult <- do.call(rbind,theGeoLookups)
```

The output is a single data frame with the content from `geo.lookup()`.

```
> thePlaces
   state state.name       county.name place                                        place.name
2     13    Georgia     Clarke County  3440 Athens-Clarke County unified government (balance)
21    35 New Mexico Bernalillo County  2000                                  Albuquerque city
22    49       Utah       Utah County   540                                       Alpine city
23    53 Washington     Skagit County  1990                                    Anacortes city
```

**UPDATE (02Dec2017):** As I did some additional testing on the complete list of cities provided by @Christopher, I noticed that sometimes `geo.lookup()` fails to return valid data at the place level, so the output only has 2 columns: `state` and `state.name`.

```
> # failure case: Astoria, NY
> 
> geo.lookup(place="Astoria",state="NY")
  state state.name
1    36   New York
>
```

In this situation, `do.call(rbind,theGeoLookups)` fails because the all data frames do not have the same columns. This is easily mitigated with some additional logic within the anonymous function in `lapply()`, which I added in the original code block.

Comment: Before I mark as solved: For some reason, the county FIPS is missing? And the city name of the input dat should be at front.Tried rbind(dat,theGeoLookups)  but didn't work.

Comment: The output fields should be called "statefp, countyfp, classfp".